# How to call validation of Textbox on value change of other component in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-redux, jsx

Want to call validation of Textbox from value change of other custom component which sets value in state.

Handlers:

```
handleValueChange = (val, elementName) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [elementName]: val
    });
};

handleSelectOptionTab = tab => {
    console.log("tab : ", tab)//tab :  {discountType: "Amount"}
    this.setState({ ...this.state, ...tab });
};
```

Input components:

```
<Textbox
  tabIndex="1"
  name="discount"
  id={"discount"}
  type="number"
  value={_.toString(this.state.discount)}
  placeholder="Enter discount"
  onChange={val => this.handleValueChange(val, "discount")}
  onBlur={() => {}}
  validate={this.state.validate}
  validationCallback={res => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      hasDiscountError: res
    });
  }}
  validationOption={
    this.state.discountType === "Percent"
      ? {
          name: "discount",
          required: true,
          reg: /regext-for-percent/,
          regMsg:"validation msg 1"
        }
      : {
          name: "discount",
          required: true,
          reg: /regex-for-amount/,
          regMsg: "Validation msg 2"
        }
  }
/>

//Options: "Amount", "Percent"
//This is selectable optional buttons where user can choose anyone among multiple options (discountType: "Amount" or discountType: "Percent")
<OptionalButton
  selection={this.state}
  identifier={"discountType"}
  tabIndex="2"
  onSelect={tab => this.handleSelectOptionTab(tab)}
  options={DISCOUNT_TYPES}
/>
```

Validation of `Textbox` is working fine on value change and focused out from `Textbox` but if value is already present and `this.state.discountType` is change from `OptionalButton` in that case validation is not working.

Example: `Textbox` value is `10000` with Type selected as `"Amount"` which is valid but as Type is changed to `"Percent"` then `Textbox` should show validation error.

Comment: How is `TextBox` component implemented? Is that implemented in a third party library?

Comment: high quality answers requires high quality questions. Try to add everything people might need to help you.
Here is the link I found that seems to match the Textbox component API: https://edwardfhsiao.github.io/react-inputs-validation/

Comment: since discountType is in your state, changing it should trigger a re-render and give a different object to validationOptions. If this is not working I would honestly suspect the library isn't working properly and adapting to prop changes

Comment: Textbox component: ```{ Textbox } from "react-inputs-validation"```

Comment: @Prem can you show us this method `handleSelectOptionTab`? thanks

Comment: Hi @tudor.gergely, I updated the question by adding those handlers.

Comment: hey @Prem , I think you need to set the validate flag when changing tabs, check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also update this.state.validate after changing the tab. The issue is that the textbox is unaware that the tab change needs a revalidation, so you need to tell it using the this.state.validate value.

Change you handleSelectOptionTab method like this:

```
handleSelectOptionTab = tab => {
    console.log("tab : ", tab)//tab :  {discountType: "Amount"}
    // try and use a function inside setState, instead of an object
    this.setState(oldState => ({ ...oldState, ...tab, validate: true }));
};
```

and then inside your validationCallback

```
  validationCallback={res => {
    this.setState(oldState => ({
      ...oldState,
      hasDiscountError: res,
      validate: false // to not trigger another validation again
    }));
  }}
```

Comment: Hi @tudor.gergely, The solution is almost valid the only problem is due to async calls. I had to modify handler as :
```
handleSelectOptionTab = tab => {
  this.setState({ ...tab }, 
  () => {this.toggleValidate(true);
});
};
``` 
Where ```toggleValidate``` sets validate in state.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, I didn't know about that. If it helped you can approve the answer (if you consider it helped). I'll update it to reflect your changes due to async calls

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe option component is change then trigger this.handleValueChange(val, "discount").

You use ref for reach component.

Following code to use ref

For example div element

```
const refTest = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>()
```

And use for component

```
<div className="App" ref={refTest}>
```

I don't know which use to component so example is div element.

Then you should trigger **"handleValueChange"** event for **"refTest"** component